# Angular service is undefined in component method with custom TS decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I am trying to add a custom method decorator to an angular component function to add some logging functionality.

The component method that I am decorating internally calls an angular service function I injected into the component. 
Unfortunately, when running the code the injected service is picked up as undefined.

The example code below:

```
function myCustomDecorator(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  const originalValue = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
    const result = originalValue.apply(target, ...args);
    //Do some other stuff
    return result;
  }
  return descriptor;
}

@Component()
class myComponentClass implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.functionIWantToDecorate();
  }

  @myCustomDecorator
  private functionIWantToDecorate() {
    this.myService.someServiceFunction();
  }
}
```

Causes a "Can't call someServiceFunction of undefined" error.
Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: I believe if you have the decorator function like that, you should remove the braces, so just have `@myCustomDecorator`

Comment: @PierreDuc good point - but underlying problem with the injectable persists...

Comment: Ill post an answer which is easier to read than code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you immediately return a descriptor from your decorator, you should not use the braces `()`. Also the `this` context is lost, try using the `this` which is in the descriptor value. Besides that, when you use `apply`, you should not use the spread operator. If you want to use that, you have to use `call`:

```
function myCustomDecorator(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  const originalValue = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function(this: Function, ...args: any[]) {
    const result = originalValue.call(this, ...args);
    // or --> const result = originalValue.apply(this, args);
    //Do some other stuff
    return result;
  }
  return descriptor;
}
```

Comment: Using this pattern in my NestJS application, which is comparable to Anguar framework-wise, it is not working. I am curious if this solved the authors problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is caused by the fact that inside the decorator `target` is the class not the instance of the class. Decorators are applied on class creation, and thus could not have access to the instance when they are called. You can acces the current object when the function is actually called:

```
descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
  const result = originalValue.apply(this, ...args); // this not target 
  //Do some other stuff
  return result;
}
```